# MySQL Website Configuration in Visual Studio 2015 Failed

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

FYI, I installed MySql Installer 5.7.21.0 based on developer option. I have Visual Studio 2015. I created a ASP.net MVC Project and I can see 'MySQL Website Configuration' on top of the Solution Explorer window. But when I click on it, the system shows following message:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Mysql.ConnectorInstaller
>   version=6.10.5.0, Version=6.10.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.

System cannot find the file specified"

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: As well as MySQL (server) do you have the 'Connector/NET' driver installed? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.10.html This will give you the drivers needed to use in your code

Comment: Yes, Because I installed  MySQL Installer community 5.7.21.0 full pack. and .net connector content files exist in install location and all related DLL files are appeared in Reference Manager list

Comment: Ah ok - just checking. I must admit I've always manually set up MySQL connectivity in VS. I usually install the relevant MySQL packages from NuGet then set up Web.Config. Back when I started using MySQL (~v6.5) it never worked via the VS dialogs for me. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Thank you @scgough
The problem is solve based on the following solution.
Anyway, Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded MySQL Connector 6.10.5 to version 6.8.8 and the problem is solved!

The issue is because of Visual Studio Version. Connector which is available on MySQL Installer community 5.7.21.0 full pack is configured for Visual Studio 2017. So you have to downgrade your connector to lower version if you want to work with Visual Studio 2015.

So you do not need to reinstall full MySQL package. Just uninstall MySQL Connector from Windows Program and features and install version 6.8.8 from the following link.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html